# Python:Count occurrences of letters in a string

Tags: python, string

I'm looking for a way to count the number of occurrences of a given letter in a string, if a letter appears more than once, use the first formula, if it does not repeat it use the second formula.

```py
def Entropy(n):
    probability= [n_x / len(n) for x, n_x in collections.Counter(n).items()]
    from collections import Counter
    a = Counter(n)
    if a > 1:
        entropy = [-p_x * math.log2(p_x) for p_x in probability]
        return sum(entropy)
    else:
        entropy2 = [-math.log2(r_x) for r_x in probability]
        return sum(entropy2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`most_common`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) function.

The example below will print

```
{'method': 0, 'most_common': 2, 'entropy_sum': 1.584962500721156, 'string': 'coucou'}
{'method': 1, 'most_common': 1, 'entropy_sum': 8.0, 'string': 'abcd'}
```

```py
import math
import collections as cl


def Entropy(_s):
    probability = [n_x / len(_s) for x, n_x in cl.Counter(_s).items()]
    most_common = cl.Counter(_s).most_common(1)[0][1]
    if most_common > 1:
        method = 0
        entropy = [-p_x * math.log2(p_x) for p_x in probability]
    else:
        method = 1
        entropy = [-math.log2(r_x) for r_x in probability]
    return {"method": method,
            "most_common": most_common,
            "entropy_sum": sum(entropy),
            "string": _s
            }


if __name__ == "__main__":
    strings = [
        "coucou",
        "abcd"
    ]
    for _s in strings:
        ans = Entropy(_s)
        print(ans)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will do.

```
from collections import Counter
import math
def Entropy(n):
    a = Counter(n)
    probability= [n_x / len(n) for x, n_x in a.items()]
    flag = 0
    for items in a:
        if a[items] > 1:
            flag = 1

    if flag == 1:
        entropy = [-p_x * math.log2(p_x) for p_x in probability]
        return sum(entropy)
    else:
        entropy2 = [-math.log2(r_x) for r_x in probability]
        return sum(entropy2)
print(Entropy("Hello World"))
```